# UITableViewCell's textLabel.text is being partially substituted by ellipsis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with several UITableViewcells (UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle). When the user taps on one of cells, I push a detail VC that allows the user to change the text of the cell. When I pop this ViewController, the text on the cell appears abbreviated with an ellipsis:

**Before:**

[image: Before editing]

**After:**
After changing the text to "Wartyrl" and popping the detail VC.

[image: After editing]

If I tap on any other cell, the ellipsis disappears and the correct text is displayed. What might be causing this?

This is the code that changes the text of the cell (via a delegate method):

```
#pragma mark - FRREditTaskViewControllerDelegate
-(void) editTaskViewController:(FRREditTaskViewController *)sender 
          didChangeNameForTask:(FRRFlatTask *)aTask{
    NSIndexPath *idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.pendings indexOfObject:aTask] inSection:0];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:idx].textLabel.text = aTask.name;
}
```

BTW, this code is called *before popping the detail VC and while the UITableViewController is still hidden*. I don't know if this is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the *textLabel* hesitates to resize its width. If its too adamant to change, just reload the tableView directly using `[tableView reloadData]`.

If you don't want to reload the entire tableView, you can reload just a particular cell like that following.

```
NSIndexPath *idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.pendings indexOfObject:aTask] inSection:0];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:idx] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This will show a nice fade animation when changing the *textLabel's* text of the cell.

Comment: I was hesitating to reloadData, but it might be the only way. Is there a method to force the the cell to resize?

Answer (score 2):

When the cell is created, the UILabel is only large enough to handle the initial text (it doesn't dynamically resize). Calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` after changing the text (end of your `didChangeNameForTask` method) should make it display properly.

Comment: Is'n there any way to force it to resize?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `[cell.textLabel sizeToFit]`.

In many cases it's cleaner to instead update your internal data and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. That way you don't have so many pieces monkeying with the implementation details of the cell (when you change your mind on how to lay it out). It also ensures that your real data matches the cell.

Even *better* in most cases is to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass called `TaskTableViewCell`. You hand it a `Task` and it observes the `Task` with KVO, managing its own layout (including calling `sizeToFit` when needed). That way you don't need delegate methods to tell you when it updates. When the task changes, the cell automatically updates itself. This moves all the layout issues into the cell class and out of the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) editTaskViewController:(FRREditTaskViewController *)sender 
      didChangeNameForTask:(FRRFlatTask *)aTask{

    NSIndexPath *idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.pendings indexOfObject:aTask] inSection:0];


    UITableViewCell *thiscell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:idx];

    thiscell.textLabel.text =[nsstring stringwithFormat:@"%@",aTask.name];

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:idx] withRowAnimation:NO];//if u dont want to use reload data then use like this or use

    //- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation


}
```

Comment: i have changed my answer .please review again and reply